# Why is my element floating to the bottom of its div

Tags: html, css

http://thepositiveclassroom.princetonsquarepress.com/dd-product/the-positive-classroom-method/

On this page the Take A Look button is staying to the bottom of its div, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Also, why do you have empty paragraphs before and after the button? If it's for spacing, use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floated elements need be first in html markup. Or remove float and add `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

You got to put the

```
html .singular-dd-product #primary #content .entry-header p {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  float: left;
}
```

on `float:left`!

**Edit:** You have a very wicked responsive-design-rule-set.

I would go for

```
.p ( before button )
{ display:inline-block; }

a. ( the button )
{ display:inline-block; }
```

Then you can work with `vertical-align`.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the empty `<p>` tags that are encapsulating the "Not Sure" text.

Remove the `float:right;` from the button.

Then add `display:inline-block;` to the button.  If you want more space between the top and bottom borders, add padding to `.product_sample_download`